# Resque worker gives out "NoMethodError: undefined method `perform`"

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, resque

I have no idea what I have done here, but I have attempted to get one controller in Rails to queue a job onto Resque, which then a worker connects to and does the heavy lifting (I.E. comparisons, database entries).
However, the tasks are not even running, since there are no clear instructions for setting Resque up.

Copy and paste's below:
[Also available in Gist format!](http://gist.github.com/645576)

This is the exception line from Hoptoad:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method 'perform' for Violateq:Module
```

This is the contents of the "worker" file:

```
module Violateq
  @queue = :violateq

  def perform(nick, rulenumber)
    # Working for the weekend!!!
    puts "I got a nick of #{nick} and they broke #{rulenumber}"
    @violation = Violation.new(nick, rulenumber)
    puts "If you got this far, your OK"
    log_in(:worker_log, {:action => "Violate d=perfom", :nick => nick, :rulenumber => rulenumber, :status => "success"})
    #rescue => ex
    # notify_hoptoad(ex)
    # log_in(:worker_log, {:action => "Violate d=perfom", :nick => nick, :rulenumber => rulenumber, :status => "failure"})
  end

end
```

This is the contents of the "web_controller" file:

```
class IncomingController < ApplicationController
  require 'mail'
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token

  def create
    message = Mail.new(params[:message])
    # Push the message into the queue
    Resque.enqueue(Violateq, message.from.to_s, message.subject.to_s)
    log_in(:endpoint_log, {:action => "IncomingController d=create", :subject => message.subject, :message => message.body.decoded})
    render :text => 'success', :status => 200 # a status of 404 would reject the mail
  rescue => ex
      notify_hoptoad(ex)
      render :text => 'failure', :status => 500
  end
end
```

Thank you very much for your time, and if you would like any more information, please do not hesitate to contact me,
Luke Carpenter

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Fixed.
Changed `def perform` to `def self.perform`
Then it worked

Thanks,
Luke Carpenter

Comment: Thanks dude. This save me big time. I was reading this http://blog.redistogo.com/2010/07/26/resque-with-redis-to-go/ and their code is wrong (maybe just from a older version?) and with this it works.

Comment: This saved me too, and I was actually reading the same post that the guy above linked to.